The admin of StackExchange can't tell wherether content was generated by AI or human
I answered a gunicorn-related question and this this the result:


You are not blocked from answering, so it should be trivial for you to give a new answer to that same question with more details.  In particular, you would want to rewrite the bit where you suggest the user does what the user already said they do.  EDIT: I see that that particular question now is closed as off-topic.  As the issue went away without explanation.  Do you know whether you would be able to explain why the issue went away?  If so, we can reopen the question and you can give a more detailed answer.

I am not sure what you are asking here since you haven't explained or asked a question, but I am guessing you are wondering why your answer was deleted and why I mentioned our AI policy, so I will answer that.
The answer was deleted because it was suggesting precisely what had already been done. As very clearly stated in the question, the OP (original poster, the person who posted the question) had created the gunicorn.socket and gunicorn.service files with matching names. The only detail in your answer was about the names; there was nothing about the content of the files, and nothing about any possible explanation for the issues encountered by the OP. Therefore, since you were telling the OP to do something they had already done, I deleted your answer because it wasn't providing any new information.
In addition, the text felt like it could possibly have been generated by AI, so I also mentioned our policy against AI-generated content. Note that I did not claim your answer was AI-generated. I only mentioned the policy because you are a new user, and I thought you might not be aware of it. Yes, I felt it was likely that it was AI-generated, but I wasn't sure and cannot be sure, so I just mentioned the policy in passing. Your answer was not deleted for being AI-generated, it was deleted because it didn't answer the question.
